# Can I use non react npm packages in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is a newbie question that I have not found an answer to on the net. I would like to use this package in a react app.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/zipcodes 
I have only used react packages so far.

Comment: Yes. You can use it.

Comment: Yes you can use it and also use its utilities as Everything react does is JSX in the end as you can write pure vanilla js. So no offense using non-react packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Same way like with no-react. React community have a lot of plugins, made for react specially, but you have no limits to use any kind of library. Most of them are compatible or require wrapper creation, which will use library with it's imperative usage, but inside react component.